# CSS no funciona

Tags: html, css

Estaba intentando hacer una página sencilla para después pasarla a Electron, pero por algún motivo, el CSS no funciona.
Este es el código del index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hola</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Este es el CSS(lo reduje al máximo para comprobar que no tuviera algún error, lo cual es así):

```
@charset "UTF-8";

.h1{
    font-size: 10em;
}
```

Y esta es la estructura de archivos:

```
.
|_src
|__views
|___index.html
|__css
|___main.css
```

Usando las herramientas de desarrollador (Firefox), he verificado que el CSS aparece en el editor de estilos, y no hay ningún mensaje de error en la consola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es quitar el punto en .H1, debería quedar así:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

h1{
    font-size: 10em;
}
```

El motivo es que si pones un .h1 estás definiendo una clase

En este ejemplo, estaríamos declarando una clase llamada h1 dentro de un h1.
Tú en cambio quieres acceder directamente al método. Por lo tanto, con h1 a secas se arregla.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando usas .h1 estas seleccionando los elementos cuyas clases tienen por nombre h1, por esa razón no te funciona. Cuando usas solamente el nombre, te estás refiriendo a todos los tags html, y # se usa para delimitar por id. 
Te recomiendo la siguiente página con información : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Considera añadir la solución en código definitiva para una mejor calidad de respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Raul el .h1 en css solo sirve si en el html en h1 tuvieras `<h1 class="h1">Hola</h1>`